# How to tell if an integer is a multiple of 10 (Xcode)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can I tell whether an integer is a multiple of 10 (*i.e. 10, 20, 30, 40, etc*) in Objective-C? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with XCode itself.

Comment: Aurum Aquila - see my answer's edit.. :p I tried!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
BOOL isMultipleOfTen = !(someInt % 10);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
if((int)myNumber % 10 == 0){
  // it is
}
else {
  // it isn't
}
```

its pretty much the same for all languages afaik

**Purely for @Aurum Aquila's entertainment**

*disclaimer - DO NOT do this! lol... just a bit of fun*

```
BOOL isDone = NO;
int multiple = 1;
while(!isDone){
  for(int i = 1; i<11; i++){
    if(i*multiple==(int)numberToCheck){
      if(i==10){
        //is multiple
      }
      else{
        //isn't
      }
      isDone = YES;
    }
  }
  multiple++;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow. That's pretty good. I'm going to put that into one of my noobish classmates' assignments and see what the teacher says to them when he reviews the code. Or I'll wait until they figure out what it does.

Comment: woah there! Go easy on your usage of the word "fun".

Answer (score 1):

An entry for Aurum's challenge:

```
NSString* aString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", (int) aNumber];
bool isMultipleOf10 = [aString hasSuffix: @"0"];
```

I was also going to write a version in which I reimplement `-stringWithFormat:` for integers which would, of course, involve doing lots of explicit `n % 10` operations, but I have just lost the will to live.

Answer (score 0):

If the mod result is 0,

try C language code

```
if(no%10==0){

//number in multiple of 10

}
else{//reminder is not 0

//number is not in multiple of 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://unrestrictedknowledge.blogspot.com/2009/07/modulo-using-bitwise-operators.html